# delphi Is there a way to get captions used by OS (windows) for buttons, like ok, cancel, abort etc

Tags: delphi

To translate my application;

I am using one or more textfile(s) where the button captions, warnings, error messages are translated to the language which the user can select from a list of languages.

Translating of warnings and error- and other messages can be specific, so these should be translated by me.

I wonder if it is possible to retrieve captions for buttons like OK, Cancel, Abort, Close are retrievable from windows according to the selected display language of windows.

EDIT

the following function seem to do what I want

```
function GetButtonCaption(const ButtonType: Integer): WideString;
var
   hDll: THandle;
   Buffer: WideString;
   BufferLen: Integer;
begin

   Result := '';
   hDll := LoadLibrary('User32.dll');
   if hDLL <> 0 then
   begin
      SetLength(Buffer, 255);
      BufferLen := LoadStringW(hdll, ButtonType, PWideChar(Buffer), Length(Buffer));
      if BufferLen <> 0 then
         Result := Copy(Buffer, 1, BufferLen);
      FreeLibrary(hDll);
   end;
end;
```

there was a list of some constants as example to pass

```
const
OK_CAPTION = 800;
CANCEL_CAPTION = 801;
ABORT_CAPTION = 802;
RETRY_CAPTION = 803;
IGNORE_CAPTION = 804;
YES_CAPTION = 805;
NO_CAPTION = 806;
CLOSE_CAPTION = 807;
```

So far it does what I am  searching for.
At this point need to find where to get those identifiers/constants.

Edit2:

I found the identifiers, these are stored at the string table of user32.dll. 
Until now I can view the string table using visual studio, don't know if it is possible via Delphi.

It seems allso that, other files (dll's), like shell32.dll has it's own string table.

Finally, I think I have my answer, except someone know a better way to get these informaion.

Comment: http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/aa020502a.htm

Comment: @quasoft asker asks about the os

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My mistake

Comment: if you think that you've solved the issue you're asking for in the question, please consider to post it as an answer. [It's absolutekly fine to do it on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)